# Animation effect to get the text from top and displaying in a div using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the text from top and display it in a div using css.I have tired using w3-container class to get the text from top.But the problem is it is displaying the total content at a time from top.But i need to get the paragraphs one by one from top.Here is the code i have used.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

       <div class="panel-heading panel-blue-heading">
                 <h3 class="panel-title">Silent Features.</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

           <p class=" w3-container w3-center w3-animate-top">Patient information management.</p>

           <p class=" w3-container w3-center w3-animate-top">Doctor information management.</p>

           <p>User management.</p>

           <p>Pathology.</p>

           <p>Ward management</p>

           <p>Pharmacy</p> 

        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
             <button class="btn btn-success">
               <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>Silent Features.
             </button>
        </div>  
     </div>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

This is the link which i have used.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/x71rvf6t/

Comment: Please add your CSS into your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A raw mode to do this is to set animation on `p` and different `animation-delay` ( time to wait until animation start ) on every `p`

( i am not familiar with the  w3-animate-top but i guess it does the same thing more or less )

See below

```css
p {
  transform:translateY(-1000px);
  animation-name:from-top;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}

@keyframes from-top {
  0%  {transform:translateY(-1000px);}
  100% { transform:translateY(0)}
}

p:first-child {
  animation-delay:0;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:1s;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay:2s;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay:3s;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay:4s;
}
p:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay:5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">

  <div class="panel-heading panel-blue-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Silent Features.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <p>Patient information management.</p>

    <p>Doctor information management.</p>

    <p>User management.</p>

    <p>Pathology.</p>

    <p>Ward management</p>

    <p>Pharmacy</p>

  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success">
                   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>Silent Features.
                 </button>
  </div>
</div>
```